# The problem with discrete differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, manifolds, discrete-calculus

Let us see an erroneous deduction:
$$x^2=x^2,~\forall x \in \Bbb R,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^2=x \cdot x,~\forall x \in \Bbb R ,$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2=\underbrace{x+x+...+x}_{x ~\text{times}},~\forall x \in \Bbb N ,$$
I want to know the logical deception in differentiating the equation to get,
$$2x=x,~\forall x \in \Bbb N ,$$
$$\Rightarrow 2=1.$$

Is it a problem of discrete differentiability?, as I feel the forward difference of $x^2$ is $D_{+}(x^2)=\frac{(x+1)^2-x^2}{1}=2x+1$ which is not equal to the backward difference of $D_{-}(x^2)=\frac{x^2-(x-1)^2}{1}=2x-1$.

OR

Can I claim that differentiation cannot be sensible in a non-manifold structure $\Bbb N$?

Comment: The biggest issue is that the number of terms on the right hand side is a function of $x$.

Comment: So the right hand side is a composition involving non-differentiable function, right?